# Non-ambiguous wording for 'Backend'

Tags: project-management, wording

When discussing a general and abstract project idea I often use the terms frontend and backend for GUI and well.. backend.

Often however, some people misunderstand frontend as the part of GUI used by 'customers' and backend as a seperat GUI for administrative personell etc.

I think I get where they come from (CMS or DMS probably use backend in that sense) but I am struggling with making a point when halve the people don't understand what I'm saying.

Is this a more common problem in German speaking countries? Is it my fault? Does anyone else have these problems?

Are there any synonyms for backend that mean the `real` backend (data access layer, non-gui functionalities etc.) and not the CMS/DMS backend which I could use?

Comment: server side? Or maybe business layer?

Comment: I can't say that we here in Germany use "back-end" very often for "graphical administrative interface". We do use "back-office" software for that meaning, though, so maybe people are just micing up their terms.

Comment: back-office software... hm.. that sounds good. will try that out this afternoon. thanks for the hint!
ad 'business layer': I kinda feel only people with knowledge about multitier architecture would get that - and those probably know which backend I initially meant. Still thanks for the input!

Comment: Updated to put the German piece in the title that is key.  Question - are you looking for an _english_ or _german_ word?  If English what's the german part about?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: just because the OP mentioned his thought about German speaking countries, I do not see a reason to restrict the question to this case.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: I only happened to come across that when talking to german/austrian customers/partners - so I wanted to see if this was a german problem and maybe some other wordings established in non-german countries. 
I am looking for an english word here - sorry for the confusion

Comment: "server" & "browser" will do.

Comment: well that's the thing @thomas junk. I try to tell them how we could have a multitude of frontends using RESTful webservices on the backend. Establishing 'browser' as a synonym for frontend would kinda go against my argumentation. But maybe I could use 'server software' for backend and keep the frontend.

Comment: I would say something like "Wenn man auf Serverseite mit REST-Services arbeitet, kann man daraus verschiedene Anzeigeformate im Browser generieren"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "backend" is not offcially defined, so there is no "real" backend. For example, in my current working context, I would call the database a backend component (even if it does run on the same machine, maybe embedded in the program's process), but not a "data access layer".

So my suggestion is

- whenever you use the word backend, give a clear definition of what **you** mean in the specific context
- or, name the backend component you are talking of more specifically (the database, the web service, a non-gui library, a background monitor, a network service, and so on )

Answer (score 1):

This is because "backend" can mean a lot of things. Without context it has no meaning.

For instance:
In a CMS it is not uncommon to actually call the administrative interface "the backend". Try a search for "Wordpres backend." and you'll see what I mean.

[Wikipedia list of front and back ends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends)

Answer (score 1):

In the current state-of-the-art english, "backend" is not defined on the context of systems engineering, therefore, no synonyms or antonyms.

In the current state-of-the-art systems engineering "backend" is generally understood as everything that a user does not directly interact with. In another words, it's all that infrastructure only reached by servers. So a web server is front end because a user might write a HTTP request in Fiddler (although highly unlike) and a database server **might** also be front-end because a user might sniff the network and catch a "SELECT * FROM myTable" going to `192.168.0.4`, somewhere he can call a pipe or something else.

In other scenarios "backend" is also a gigantic stack composed of many layers such as caching, security, OR mapping and etc... not only a "business-layer" and "database-layer"...

But if you put a gun in my head and you know... i would use the "Hidden-Stack" or maybe "Server-Side"... they are not perfect... but theres a gun in my head...